# Hypothesis testing a binary predictive model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models

I would like to perform a hypothesis test to determine if a particular predictive model is a true improvement, or just attributable to randomness.  Below is my suggested formulation; the motivation and context follow.

$y(x)$ is a function mapping finite set $X$ (of known cardinality) to $\{0,1\}$.  $y$ is unknown, but $\hat y = y$ with probability $p_{\hat y}$.

A new function $\hat z$ is introduced, with the claim that $\hat z$ is superior to $\hat y$, in that $\hat z = y$ with probability $p_{\hat z} > p_{\hat y}$.

How can we test the hypothesis: **Is $\hat z$ truly superior to $\hat y$, or is the difference attributable to randomness?**

I believe the following is the correct model: An urn has $|X|$ marbles, which are black with probability $p_{\hat y}$ and otherwise red.  We scoop out $k$ marbles (without replacement).  Let $b$ equal the number of black marbles we scooped out, and $r$ the number of red.  Let $H_k$ be a random variable equal to $r - b$ for a given trial scooping $k$ marbles.

Let $t(k) = p(H_k \ge (p_{\hat z} - p_{\hat y}) \cdot |X|)$.  The hypothesis is valid with probability $\max_k t(k)$.

1. Is this correct?
2. If not: What is the correct hypothesis test?
3. If yes: What is $\max_k t(k)$?

---

The [Kaggle Titanic competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic) is very popular, where, given information about a passenger, you must predict if they survived.  A very simple predictor can achieve 76% accuracy; the best can achieve 82-84%.  I'd like a means to test if, e.g. a model with 82% accuracy is really better than one with 80%.

Comment: $H_k$ is hypergeometric rv, I believe